Mental health condition
I need to know a term that refers to a person who is mentally non-disabled but has a kind of mental issue because of which sometimes acts weird; such as, starts laughing suddenly or crying or using abusive language, then they come back to the normal state and act normal.
I found one but I'm not sure if it is right.

Disruptive mental health


There's a psychology and neuroscience Stack Exchange which might be able to give you the actual medical term. If there is one. (It would depend on your definition of disability - various forms of neurodivergence aren't necessarily considered disabilities by people who have them.)

There are so many different mental health conditions that we do not have one single word that covers them all. As @StuartF says, some forms of neurodivergence are not considered 'mental disabilities'.

I didn't write, mentally disabled, I wrote mentally non-disabled e.g. good mental health condition.

We don't necessarily agree with your characterization of this as a non-malady. Native speakers not in the psychology profession might have any number of terms to describe such behavior, and which one applies best would be a matter of opinion.

Ask the person involved if they have talked to a doctor/professional about their inability to control their strong emotions OR their sporadic episodes when they appear to be suffering distress. This is not a site for diagnosis.

@Mari-LouA Why is everybody assuming this is about diagnosis? That's a leap. The OP said: I need to know a term The question received an upvote, I notice.

@Lambie   Why are you presuming you know the person described and you are qualified or know enough to give a diagnosis. If you had said, Perhaps this could be…; I'm not qualified but it sounds like..., or You should not say this person has Tourette's without being sure/consulting a specialist, but it might be   Also. Not my upvote. Also, I voted to close this question for being off-topic.

@Mari-LouA You are not reading me properly. So be it. This: "Why are you presuming you know the person described and you are qualified or know enough to give a diagnosis." is not true. I do not give a diagnosis NOR do I say I know the person. How can you possibly ascribe either of those to me? Vote to close is your right but you needn't say I am saying things I am not saying.

@Lambie  Nearly all the answers are different. Not one has the same idea, or medical term, did you notice? See Seowjooheng's original answer before users said that bi-polar was a leap. And then it was edited to autistic meltdown! What!? The OP is indeed looking for a term for a description that could feasibly fit a myriad of illnesses or conditions. This site is not a good fit, the question is inappropriate on a language site dedicated to learners, the OP has to provide more detail, details which they may be unable to give.

@Mari-LouA I don't know what the person is looking for. They are staying silent. That said, I see nothing untoward in trying to match a term with a description. There are all sorts of learners. Maybe this person is a writer and is looking for terms. It just is not a big deal. I have deleted my answer because I disagree with the comments re my trying to "diagnose  something". People are so judgmental and jump without reading and assume all sorts of things.

@Lambie with the exception of astralbee, whose answer I did not cast any vote, I downvoted all these answer and I'm tempted to downvote the question, if the OP does not clarify exactly what they are looking for. The OP's suggestion describes the medical condition or the behaviour patterns of some serious mental health issues.

Saying someone "acts weird" sounds like a personal opinion. If you mean they act unconventionally or disparate from social norms, that doesn't mean anything is wrong with them at all. Their differences to you could just be cultural. But, if you mean their behaviour is socially unacceptable then you may be speaking about emotional, behavioural, interpersonal or personality issues.
While it is true that some mental health disorders affect the above, to be defined as a mental health disorder the issue must include clinically significant disturbances in cognition, emotion regulation, behaviour etc, cause distress or impaired functioning, and be rooted in biological, psychological, or developmental processes.
To be clear, this is not a diagnosis of any individual. Only a medical professional can say if an individual has a mental health disorder or not; likewise, emotional, behavioural, interpersonal or personality issues would be identified by a professional in psychology or similar specialty.

Yes, acts weird does sound like a personal opinion. Right. I do not understand why everyone seems to assume this is about diagnosis. This answer does not deserve a dv.

Edit
We could say generally this person is struggling with their mental health and has wild mood swings.  It's not appropriate for non-medical professionals to use psychiatric terms on a person.
(Described in the links below are some psychiatric terms used in my original answer.  They are for the medical specialists and are for our information only.)
Cyclothymia
Bipolar Disorder:

As diagnoses go, that is a very big jump from a very limited description.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I think you’re right.

The somewhat vague OP description could fit an autistic 'meltdown'.

Thanks again, @Michael Harvey.   Incorporated.

Or a panic attack, anxiety attack, or similar. I once had a colleague at work who behaved like that and it transpired she was drunk, having been secretly drinking whisky at her desk. So I would prefer something very general such as 'this person is struggling with their mental health'.

I doubt this was your intent, but this answer is written as if a person, when speaking English, should guess a psychiatric diagnosis and then use that to refer to someone's behavior in a general sense. I don't think that's good advice for English language learners. Please remember that's what answers on this site are for.

Thanks, @Dan Getz.  It certainly wasn't my intention.   I've edited my answer.

This answer is just descriptive. No one is diagnosing anyone.

The term  "disruptive mental health" is not a specific diagnosis or condition.
If I understood correctly, you are asking:

"What term describes someone without a diagnosed mental disorder but who occasionally experiences sudden emotional or behavioral changes?"

The symptoms which OP mentioned is called Pathological laughter and crying
Also called: PBA, pseudobulbar affect. Inappropriate involuntary, sudden laughing and crying due to a nervous system disorder. This behavior may have various causes,

1. Pseudobulbar Affect (PBA):.
.
A condition characterized by sudden, uncontrollable, and inappropriate episodes of laughing or crying.


2. Pathological laughter and crying:.
.
A form of affect lability involving frequent, involuntary emotional outbursts. It is often associated with neurological conditions such as Alzheimer's disease, ALS, MS, Parkinson's disease, stroke, and traumatic brain injury.

It's essential to note that only a qualified mental health professional can provide an accurate diagnosis and guidance. If someone you know is experiencing these symptoms, consulting a mental health expert for proper evaluation and support is crucial.

mentally non-disabled is fine as a descriptive by an OP.

i found "non-disabled" here:  https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/inclusive-communication/inclusive-language-words-to-use-and-avoid-when-writing-about-disability

@xeesid I have given the terms thatdescribes the symptoms. The cause can only be detected by a qualified mental health professional. I found , the term "mentally non-disabled" at some places online. This behavior may have various causes, This behavior may have various causes,  The symptoms  is called Pathological laughter and crying Also called: PBA, pseudobulbar affect

In US slang, the word 'spaz' can describe a person like that. The meaning has changed over time and it does not mean the same thing from person to person. It is sometimes used to describe someone who is either excessively energetic, or easily startled into having a physical response, or spontaneously starts to move their body for no reason, though it could also mean a very clumsy person, or even someone who is nerdy or uncool. It is not typically a way to indicate that someone has an actual psychological or physical disorder. It is sometimes a pejorative term but can also be used in a teasing or endearing way. The word may be falling into disuse because of its origins as a derogatory term for physical disability.
However, in British English and possibly other regions outside of the US, "spaz"—along with "spastic", which it is an abbreviation of—is an extremely offensive slur. You should be very careful not to use it if you are unsure whether it is a slur in the region where you are saying it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spastic_(word)

This answer is not about a term. The word you mention is merely derogatory.

@Lambie My answer includes a link to a thorough explanation of the word's history and use. It is not a merely derogatory term where I live. The question is, to my eyes, not asking for medical terminology. I base this on the fact that the OP specified a "mentally non-disabled" person and used the phrase "sometimes acts weird". Though they could have explained more clearly, I reasonably assume that the hypothetical person they have described does not need a diagnosis because they are not ill.

The word in most circles is considerered really awful. It's a slur in AmE too. Unless used as a joke.
